# Xpcom error when using AutoJSContext with GeckoFX 29.0 VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, geckofx

I'm using GeckoFX 29.0 with AutoJSContext and when i launch my app, it gives me the following error :

```
Xpcom.Initialize must be called before using of any xulrunner/gecko-fx services
```

I understand that i must initialize Xpcom before calling AutoJS but in my code XPcom(xullrunner) is initialize before the Sub named "GeckoFxError"

```
Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/xulrunner")
        Gecko.GeckoPreferences.Default("extensions.blocklist.enabled") = False
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub
    Sub New1()
        Dim _memoryService = Xpcom.GetService(Of nsIMemory)("@mozilla.org/xpcom/memory-service;1")
        _memoryService.HeapMinimize(False)
    End Sub

    Private Sub GeckoFXerror(sender As Object, e As Gecko.JavascriptErrorEventArgs) Handles GeckoWebBrowser1.JavascriptError
        Dim text As String = "window.alert = function(){};"
        Dim text2 As String = "window.confirm = function(){};"
        Dim text3 As String = "window.open = function(){};"
        Dim text4 As String = "window.prompt = function(){};"
        Using context As AutoJSContext = New AutoJSContext(GeckoWebBrowser1.Window.JSContext)
            Dim result As String = ""
            context.EvaluateScript(text, result)
        End Using
        Using context As AutoJSContext = New AutoJSContext(GeckoWebBrowser1.Window.JSContext)
            Dim result As String = ""
            context.EvaluateScript(text2, result)
        End Using
        Using context As AutoJSContext = New AutoJSContext(GeckoWebBrowser1.Window.JSContext)
            Dim result As String = ""
            context.EvaluateScript(text3, result)
        End Using
        Using context As AutoJSContext = New AutoJSContext(GeckoWebBrowser1.Window.JSContext)
            Dim result As String = ""
            context.EvaluateScript(text4, result)
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Thanks for your help and i think it's easy to solve but i haven't found any solution in more than one hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/xulrunner")` before calling `InitializeComponent()` and it should work.

Comment: I fixed this issue a long time ago but thank as well